# World map with R?

Tags: r

I have an array that tells me the number of observations per country.

```
countries <- structure(c(532L, 3L, 1L, 15L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 16L, 2L, 43L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 16L, 13L, 2L, 2L, 
9L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 10L, 11L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 
7L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 20L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 5L, 76L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Dim = 63L, .Dimnames = structure(list(
    c("United States", "Argentina", "Armenia", "Australia", "Austria", 
    "Bangladesh", "Belarus", "Belgium", "Brazil", "Bulgaria", 
    "Canada", "Chile", "China", "Colombia", "Croatia", "Cuba", 
    "Cyprus", "Czech Republic", "Dominican Republic", "Ecuador", 
    "Estonia", "France", "Germany", "Greece", "Guatemala", "Hong Kong", 
    "India", "Indonesia", "Iran", "Ireland", "Israel", "Italy", 
    "Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Latvia", "Malaysia", "Mexico", "Netherlands", 
    "New Zealand", "Norway", "Peru", "Philippines", "Poland", 
    "Portugal", "Romania", "Russia", "Saudi Arabia", "Serbia", 
    "Singapore", "Slovakia", "South Africa", "South Korea", "Spain", 
    "Sri Lanka", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Thailand", "Turkey", 
    "Ukraine", "United Kingdom", "Uruguay", "Uzbekistan", "Venezuela"
    )), .Names = ""))
```

I am able to plot a map using the maps library. But I would appreciate the help in making it look better.

```
library(maps)
map(database="world")
map(database="world", col=countries, fil=countries)
legend("topleft", fill = countries, legend = countries, col = countries)
box()
```

The first big problem is the legend. A continuous scale would probably look better than one color per country, not sure how to do that. After fixing that, anything that can be done to make it look better would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

---

I can make a dynamic map using googleVis, but I'm having troubles with making an static map using ggplot2. For example, with ggplot2 it looks like I have no one in the US.

This is my code

```
#Load My data
countries <- structure(list(country = c("United States", "Afghanistan", "Albania", 
                                        "Argentina", "Armenia", "Australia", "Austria", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", 
                                        "Belarus", "Belgium", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Brazil", "Bulgaria", 
                                        "Canada", "Chile", "China", "Colombia", "Croatia", "Cuba", "Cyprus", 
                                        "Czech Republic", "Denmark", "Dominican Republic", "Ecuador", 
                                        "Egypt", "El Salvador", "Estonia", "Finland", "France", "Germany", 
                                        "Greece", "Guatemala", "Haiti", "Hong Kong", "Hungary", "Iceland", 
                                        "India", "Indonesia", "Iran", "Ireland", "Israel", "Italy", "Japan", 
                                        "Jordan", "Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Korea, South", "Latvia", "Libya", 
                                        "Lithuania", "Macedonia", "Malaysia", "Malta", "Mexico", "Moldova", 
                                        "Morocco", "Netherlands", "New Zealand", "Nicaragua", "Niger", 
                                        "Nigeria", "Norway", "Pakistan", "Panama", "Peru", "Philippines", 
                                        "Poland", "Portugal", "Romania", "Russia", "Saudi Arabia", "Serbia", 
                                        "Singapore", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "Somalia", "South Africa", 
                                        "South Korea", "Spain", "Sri Lanka", "Sweden", "Switzerland", 
                                        "Taiwan", "Thailand", "Turkey", "Ukraine", "United Arab Emirates", 
                                        "United Kingdom", "Uruguay", "Uzbekistan", "Venezuela", "Zimbabwe"
), count = c(1224L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 40L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 8L, 
             2L, 40L, 3L, 106L, 4L, 16L, 10L, 8L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 
             1L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 10L, 26L, 41L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 34L, 2L, 3L, 
             10L, 4L, 19L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 36L, 
             1L, 1L, 31L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 29L, 7L, 11L, 13L, 
             21L, 5L, 9L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 22L, 2L, 42L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 
             5L, 13L, 2L, 157L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 1L)), .Names = c("country", "count"
             ), row.names = c(NA, -93L), class = "data.frame")

#Make dynamic map
library(googleVis)
# Make the map!
geoMap <- gvisGeoMap(countries, locationvar="country", numvar="count",
                     options=list(dataMode="regions"))
plot(geoMap)

#Make ggplot2 map
library(maps)
library(ggplot2)
#load world data
world <- map_data("world")

#Delete Antarctica
world <- subset(world,region!="Antarctica")
#Add count
world$count<-countries$count[match(world$region,countries$country,nomatch=NA)]
qplot(long, lat, data = world, group = group, fill=count, geom ="polygon",ylab="",xlab="")
```

Why is the ggplot2 map wrong? How can I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Now, now, let's not be snarky. @Ignacio: Try out **maps** or **maptools** and update your question when you have specific questions about those packages.

Comment: +1 for a reproducible example showing input data, what you tried and why it wasn't suitable. This is a good question. @rawr Thomas is right: leave the snarking to [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25312/r-public) please. Aside from being annoying, it's also unwarranted in this case.

Comment: at what point am I allowed to be snarky? googling "r maps," the first hit is the maps package. I believe the original question was something along the lines of "can r do maps?"

Comment: In @rawr's defense, the original question provided data, and asked "I want to plot maps. Can R do this?"

Comment: @Ignacio `ggplot`'s map looks incorrect because the names of the countries you provided in your data set do not match the names of the countries in the `map_data("world")` data set. I believe that when you plot with the `maps` and `googleVis` packages, they do some fuzzy matching of country names for you internally. With `ggplot2`, the names of the countries in your data set and the `world` data set should match. Try `countries$country[!countries$country %in% world$region]` to get a list of non-matching country names in your data set (e.g. `United States` is called `USA` in the world data).

Comment: @ialm I think the problem, or a problem, is that map_data("world") is an old map (i.e. Russia is not there). I'm looking into how to load a newer map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may not be exactly what you want, but here is a solution using the `googleVis` package.

```
# I had to change your data a little bit
countries2 <- data.frame(country=names(countries), count=as.integer(countries), 
                         stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# Install the googleVis package and load it
# install.packages("googleVis")
library(googleVis)

# Make the map!
geoMap <- gvisGeoMap(countries2, locationvar="country", numvar="count",
                 options=list(dataMode="regions"))
plot(geoMap)
```

This will make an interactive [Geo Map](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geomap.html) of your data, and when you mouse over the different regions, it should highlight it and display a pop-up of the count.

(My apologies - this question was just an excuse to try this package out :). )

If you want a static plot, I can try to make that as well.

Comment: wow, that is awesome! I would really appreciate if you can show me how to do the static version. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution.

```
#Load My data
countries <- structure(list(country = c("United States", "Afghanistan", "Albania", 
                                        "Argentina", "Armenia", "Australia", "Austria", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", 
                                        "Belarus", "Belgium", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Brazil", "Bulgaria", 
                                        "Canada", "Chile", "China", "Colombia", "Croatia", "Cuba", "Cyprus", 
                                        "Czech Republic", "Denmark", "Dominican Republic", "Ecuador", 
                                        "Egypt", "El Salvador", "Estonia", "Finland", "France", "Germany", 
                                        "Greece", "Guatemala", "Haiti", "Hong Kong", "Hungary", "Iceland", 
                                        "India", "Indonesia", "Iran", "Ireland", "Israel", "Italy", "Japan", 
                                        "Jordan", "Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Korea, South", "Latvia", "Libya", 
                                        "Lithuania", "Macedonia", "Malaysia", "Malta", "Mexico", "Moldova", 
                                        "Morocco", "Netherlands", "New Zealand", "Nicaragua", "Niger", 
                                        "Nigeria", "Norway", "Pakistan", "Panama", "Peru", "Philippines", 
                                        "Poland", "Portugal", "Romania", "Russia", "Saudi Arabia", "Serbia", 
                                        "Singapore", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "Somalia", "South Africa", 
                                        "South Korea", "Spain", "Sri Lanka", "Sweden", "Switzerland", 
                                        "Taiwan", "Thailand", "Turkey", "Ukraine", "United Arab Emirates", 
                                        "United Kingdom", "Uruguay", "Uzbekistan", "Venezuela", "Zimbabwe"
), count = c(1224L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 40L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 8L, 
             2L, 40L, 3L, 106L, 4L, 16L, 10L, 8L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 
             1L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 10L, 26L, 41L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 34L, 2L, 3L, 
             10L, 4L, 19L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 36L, 
             1L, 1L, 31L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 29L, 7L, 11L, 13L, 
             21L, 5L, 9L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 22L, 2L, 42L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 
             5L, 13L, 2L, 157L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 1L)), .Names = c("country", "count"
             ), row.names = c(NA, -93L), class = "data.frame")

suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(maptools)
  library(ggplot2)
})



PolygonCoords <- function(polygon) {
  polygons <- polygon@Polygons
  coords.list <- lapply(seq_along(polygons), function(i) {
    # Extract the group, sequence, area, longitude, and latitude.
    coords <- polygons[[i]]@coords
    cbind(i, 1:nrow(coords), polygons[[i]]@area, coords)
  })
  coords.df <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, coords.list))
  names(coords.df) <- c("order", "seq", "area", "long", "lat")
  return(coords.df)
}

ConvertWorldSimple <- function(mapdata, min.area = 0) {

  # min.area is the minimum size of the polygons. Setting to some
  # positive value will filter out tiny islands.


  coords.list <- lapply(mapdata@polygons, PolygonCoords)
  ncoords <- sapply(coords.list, nrow)
  coords.df <- do.call(rbind, coords.list)
  coords.df$country <- rep(mapdata@data$NAME, ncoords)
  country.group <- factor(paste(coords.df$country, coords.df$order))
  coords.df$group <- as.numeric(country.group)
  coords.df <- coords.df[coords.df$area >= min.area, ]
  return(coords.df)
}

data("wrld_simpl")
world <- ConvertWorldSimple(wrld_simpl, min.area = 0.1)
#Delete Antarctica
world <- subset(world,country!="Antarctica")

#Add count
world$count<-countries$count[match(world$country,countries$country,nomatch=NA)]
x<-quantile(world$count, na.rm=TRUE)
qplot(long, lat, data = world, group = group, fill=count, geom ="polygon",ylab="",xlab="") + 
  scale_fill_gradient(name="log(Number of\nStudents)", trans = "log")
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: For your scale problems, try a log scale (add `trans = "log"` as an argument in your `scale_fill_gradient` call).